# How to handle the asynchronous nature of Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I ran into a problem in my app.

I need to get the response data to populate my table view, but my Alamofire GET request call (which is in viewDidload) doesn't respond faster than the tableView's call to numberOfRowsInSection.

I'm not really knowledgable in software/mobile software design so I'm kind of stuck on what I need to do.

Should I just make everything wait for my Alamofire response (if so how do I do that?)? That just seems like it goes against the asynchronous nature of Alamofire.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

First you create array which will contain data that will be shown in the `UITableView`. Initialize those in the viewDidLoad. For the `numberOfRowsInSection` you will return `myArray.count`.

When you get your data, insert them into your array, (eg. from above `myArray`) and after that call `tableView.reloadData()`.

This should resolve your problems.

Comment: so why would one do this versus the completion handler as shown by Eric D. Is it to keep with the asynchronous nature of it? are you saying do the reloadData in the closure part of the Alamofire request?

Comment: well you will call reloadData inside completion handler, sorry if my answer was misleading. The idea is that you reload table after your async call finishes its job.